Vent pipe flashing for two 2" PVC vent pipes that are almost touching (1/4" apart)? How?
They're too close together to use any conventional flashing product. Standard shingled angled roof in Phoenix, AZ. They're an intake and exhaust for a gas tankless water heater. There was unfortunately a joist right above the intake so I needed a couple of 45" elbows to get around it, and the other side of the joist wasn't clear. What should I do? Thanks!

how handy are you? can you make one ?

Might have to resort to using duct seal (monkey poop) or caulk.

I ended up making something with a 4" pipe flashing, stretched sideways as wide as possible. I had to also cut vertical slits to get it over the pipes. Then, I used some of a tube of Henry roof patch to seal the slits and around the pipes where the flashing meets them. Hopefully the heat won't melt the patch and cause it to flow downward.

For a reliable flashing, fix the pipes below roof level so they go through far enough apart to have separate flashing boots, or (depending on vent type, i.e. if they are both plumbing vents) combine them into a single 3" vent below roof level.

They're an intake and exhaust for a gas tankless water heater. There was unfortunately a joist right above the intake so I needed a couple of 45" elbows to get around it, and the other side of the joist wasn't clear. Everything's glued in place so I don't think I want to repipe. I'm not sure I'm skilled enough to combine them...

You can't combine intake and exhaust into a single penetration without a special fitting that keeps them separated all the way out, but coaxial, and operating at different levels so you don't suck exhaust back in the intake (those are made, though.) PVC pipe tends to mean you should be comfortable with the idea that you'll need to cut it and glue in some more fittings, or cut and scrap a bit to replace with something that works right when the first run didn't come out well. Two pipes 1/4" apart is just about guaranteed to leak. Probably also too close unless they are very different heights

this makes sense and we probably should have done this. I think we'll have to see how it goes at this point.
